# Flash HTC 8X Telstra to unbranded ROM

Tags: htc-8x

I have a HTC 8X Telstra, but my phone has not an option in  ringtones+sounds settings for turning of camera shutter sound!

I searched and found that problem is from my career.

Is there any way to flash my phone to unbranded ROM?